How to disappear Proxy Auth Popup
chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
    function(details, callbackFn) {
        // Fetch credentials dynamically
        getAuthCredentials().then(authCredentials => {
            callbackFn({
                authCredentials: {
                    username: authCredentials.username,
                    password: authCredentials.password
                }
            });
        }).catch(error => {
            console.error("Error fetching credentials: ", error);
            callbackFn(); // Proceed without credentials if there's an error
        });
    },
    { urls: ["<all_urls>"] }, // You can customize this for specific proxy URLs
    ['asyncBlocking']
);

I have a Proxy VPN Chrome extension built in pure JavaScript. Occasionally, when a user connects to a location, an authentication popup appears, although the connection remains active and works fine. I added the username and password using Chrome's built-in callback, but the popup still shows up in rare cases. While it only appears once or twice, it's still an issue for me. I'm trying to understand why this happens.
Please suggest a solution for removing this authentication popup? The connection works fine, but I want to hide the popup. If I can prevent it from appearing, my issue will be resolved. Is there a method to hide this built-in popup in a Chrome extension?
